# Why does JavaScript skip my function?

Tags: javascript

It's one of those days when I wonder: am I losing my mind? If I step through this simple javascript function, the execution skips from line 3 to line 7.

```
function editStudy() { 
        var studyindex = document.StudyMaint.StudyList.selectedIndex;
        var studyabrv = document.StudyMaint.StudyList[index].text;  //Line 3
        var msg="Edit study "+studyabrv+"?";

        // Get the Study record id was selected in the picklist,
        // then go to Study edit screen, then

        if (confirm(msg)) {
            location.href="editStudy.php?action=UPDATE&studyindex="+studyindex+"&studyabrv="+studyabrv;
        }  //Line 7
    }
```

but my form StudyMaint is defined:

```
<body>
    <?php showUserLine(); ?>
    <form name="StudyMaint" action="Process_StudyMaint.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
    <div id="dataentrybox"> 
        <div id="innerbox">
            <div align="center">
...
```

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: What is line 3 and line 7?

Comment: There are four lines of emptiness/comments in between?

Comment: You are not actually calling the function. You call it by doing ediStudy();

Comment: @Blender the numbering was lost when I edited it to make the code readable - I think it's that the assignment to "msg" and the `confirm()` are skipped.

Comment: What happens when you do `alert(msg)` ?

Comment: I looked at the original post and the 3 and 7 that the OP had labeled

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console? Set it up to preserve the log upon page navigation in case the form is submitting. I have a feeling it says something about `index`.

Comment: also paste the code where you're calling ediStudy function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are using the wrong index variable name.  Try using the one you defined, studyindex.

Answer (score 1):

You've not defined index variable. It's better to use firebug or chrome's developer tools for debugging javascript issues.